# Zend Framework google translate usage

Tags: zend-framework, google-translate

I'm trying to translate automatic a string using the google translator! Using Zend_Http_CLient is not able to log in in the application and retrieve the translated words. It returns to me an authentication error.

I google and searched here something about it but had no success. Can someone give a hand on it and tell me where can I find some idea on how to use Zend_Gdata with Google Translate and authenticate at the service?

Thanks a lot, best regard's.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know Zend GData classes doesn't support google translate yet

source : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html

in the same page you would find a link to this : http://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/

i had give it a simple try and it seems to be working BUT note the comment in the class declaration

> Google requires attribution for their
>   Language API, please see:
>   http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Branding

hopefully that would help

please provide the error message to make your question more clear

thanks

Comment: Yeah, that´s the option I will try it with jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate', array(
    'maxredirects' => 0,
    'timeout'      => 30));

$client->setParameterGet(array(
    'v' => '1.0',
    'q' => 'Привет',
    'langpair' => 'ru|en'
    ));

$response = $client->request();



$data = $response->getBody();

$server_result = json_decode($data);

$status = $server_result->responseStatus; // should be 200
$details = $server_result->responseDetails;

$result = $server_result->responseData->translatedText;

echo $result;
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no official Google Translate, yet. But this translation adapter might help:

http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/35

Also, if you do use this, be sure to CACHE your results! You don't want to hammer the service over and over again for the same translations.

Comment: Hum, that's a good advise! Let's see how it works, I done it using jQuery and ajax request! But let's try out.